# Why aren't my HTML inputs passing on Submit of form?

Tags: php, html, forms

Edit: Yes, this is a duplicate, and the same answer is applicable. I didn't find the linked original when I searched on 3 sets of terms. Sorry!

Edit 2: yeah, `name="something"`. I feel like such an idiot.

Edit 3: Well, no. The `name` attribute fixed my text fields, but not my checkboxes! My checkboxes now read like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="dot" id="stren1" name="stren1" checked="true" disabled>
```

but still don't show up in my `var_dump`!

## Original Question:

I've been trying to save form data to a variable, and having no luck. Digging in to it, I discovered that my form data was not passing at all to my PHP! Below is a snippet from this gist (https://gist.github.com/farfromunique/35a5d6006e8d5690ca4d) :

```
<form action="store.php" method="post">
        <input name="test" value="Test" type="hidden">
        <div id="charSheet">
            <div id="clanName">
                <H1>Vampire: the Masquerade</H1>
            </div>
            <div id="plainText" class="section">
                <div id="text1" class="lefty">
                    <label>Character's Name
                        <input type="text" id="characterName">
                    </label>
                    <br />
                    <label>Player
                        <input type="text" id="player">
                    </label>
                    <br />
                    <label>Chronicle
                        <input type="text" id="chronicle">
                    </label>
                    <br />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- Snip! /-->
    <input type="Submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

Currently, `store.php` has only this in it:

```
var_dump($_REQUEST);
```

Submitting the form results in this:

```
array (size=1)
    'test' => string 'Test' (length=4)
```

Why is only my top-level, added-for-debugging input passing data? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As to your 3rd edit, disabled elements do not pass data. You either need to enable the field on post using javascript or store that information in a hidden field

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `name=""` attribute, not `id=""`.

Comment: maybe AND id, but we ger the point

Answer (score 0):

use the 'name' attribute. simple HTML